# Datatable colVis plugin showing error "headerCells[i] is undefined" when selecting column

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I having been trying to resolve this bug since morning with no effect

My Datatable is

```
  keywordDataTable = $('#keywordsTable').DataTable( {
    //stateSave: true,
    paging:   false,
    scrollY: "100%",
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    dom: 'C<"clear">lfrtip',
    colVis: {
        exclude: [ 0 ],
        showAll: 'All',
        showNone: 'None',
    }
} );
new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( keywordDataTable );
```

Everything runs fine but when i uncheck a column and try to select from `All` button or select column check again, i get this error `TypeError: headerCells[i] is undefined on line number 4156 jquery.dataTable.js` in console.
On debugging i have found that somehow column count does not update and last index for e.g. if i had 5 columns before adding (or checking ) another column. function triggered show only count 5 but it should return 6. Because of it, columns width is also not properly set.

lines from jquery.dataTables.js

```
headerCells = _fnGetUniqueThs( oSettings, tmpTable.find('thead')[0] );

        for ( i=0 ; i<visibleColumns.length ; i++ ) {
            column = columns[ visibleColumns[i] ];

        /*  (error on this line) */ headerCells[i].style.width = column.sWidthOrig !== null && column.sWidthOrig !== '' ?
                _fnStringToCss( column.sWidthOrig ) :
                '';
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug

Don't use datables bundled package

try to use cdn one i think cdn has a bug resolved for the same thing

`<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSON to bind the grid, please check your column count in column definition does not exceed the number of fields in the JSON